# React Native Firebase request for permission

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, react-native-firebase

According to react-native-firebase documentation in **Notifications/Receiving notifications**: *Before you are able to send and receive Notifications, you need to ensure that the user has granted the correct permissions*.

However, I can normally receive a push notification from the server which can open the application by tapping it, even though I haven't checked and requested any permission before. I've tested on Android only.

So my question is whether it is necessary to setup permission handling if the only thing required is to receive notifications from the server without handling them in the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview), in Android, notifications permission is in **Normal permissions** group and not in **Dangerous permissions**.

As mentioned:

> If an app declares in its manifest that it needs a **normal permission**, the system automatically grants the app that permission at install time.

And:

> To use a **dangerous permission**, your app must prompt the user to grant permission at runtime.

That's why your notification works without granting user's permission in runtime.

But for iOS, you **must** grant user's permission at runtime or it will not work.

Comment: Thanks, I also tested it out on iOS and it wouldn't work otherwise.